# Should we keep the [interaction] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-tag

I noticed we've had some suggested edits recently removing the [interaction](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interaction) tag from questions (e.g. [1](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/492)). I can understand the rationale for doing so; to be honest, quite a few questions on this site are about interactions, if not the majority. That said, I'm sure there are cases where the tag is important, although I don't have specific examples.

I'd like to have an explicit discussion about this.

- Should we keep the [interaction](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interaction) tag for some questions?
- If so, should it be used for *every* question involving interactions, or should only a subset of those have it?

Comment: Suggestion: any proposal to keep it should be accompanied by a proposed tag wiki that makes it not 90% of the questions here.

Answer (score 12):

Isn't *interaction* just a roundabout way of saying "interpersonal"? That's the entire scope of this site. This feels a bit like a ubiquitous tag that doesn't really aid in any sort of categorization of content.

Comment: totally agree, that was what I was going to say

Answer (score 2):

No, we don't need it. This kinda includes the entire site's scope. It is more general tag.

Questions about interaction should be more specific  such as social media interaction or face to face interaction. For eg., [social-interaction](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-interaction).

Comment: This internet connection posted my answer twice. :D

Comment: To be honest, even [tag:social-interaction] seems to me as "this entire stack".